# PlantUML produces error when specifying asynchronous messages

Tags: intellij-idea, uml, sequence-diagram, plantuml, puml

I have this PlantUML code (.puml)

```
@startuml
title Asynchronous Message Example

participant Alice
participant Bob

Alice -> Bob: Request
Bob --> Alice: Acknowledgment
Alice ::> Bob: Asynchronous Message
Bob ::> Alice: Asynchronous Response

@enduml
```

and I get this result:

[image]

The plantuml version I am using is:

[image]

Comment: This should be reported as a bug to the plug-in maintainers at https://github.com/esteinberg/plantuml4idea/issues.

Comment: I think it's just a versioning thing, looks like new version uses `->>` for async message, instead of `::>`, but not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous messages shall be encoded as `->>` or `<<-` according to the plantuml [online documentation on sequence diagrams](https://plantuml.com/en/sequence-diagram) and the official [language reference manual](https://plantuml.com/en/guide).

It is therefore normal that your plantuml instance complains about the use of `::>`, as it is not the correct syntax, independently of your plugin.

How to solve it:  1) Check with the author of the puml why the token `::>` was used;  2)  If the author is an automatic generator,  report a bug for the generator.